# Remove resharper property "() As" behavior in vb.net code

Tags: vb.net, resharper, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to remove the Resharper behavior that add "() As" when using TAB to complete the word "property" when defining a new property.

For example, typing "Public prop" will show the autocompletion for "property" but using TAB will add parentheses automatically.

I find this behavior extremely annoying and would like to disable it.
Unfortunately, I had no success yet.

Any ideas ?
(Pressing space instead of TAB will actually not create the parentheses and still complete but I would prefer to not change my tab habits).

Image below: Typing "Public Prop" then pressing TAB behavior (Cursor is placed at the red arrow)

[image]